# Is there a way to count observations from multiple excel files to populate a new table?

Tags: excel, loops, sas

I'm using SAS and trying to build a pretty basic dataset but want to populate these fields (ie workbook1_01MMYY) with the number of observations from specific excel workbooks with different names.

```
Date    Workbook1   Woorkbook2  Woorkbook3
01MMYY  
02MMYY
```

All workbooks follow a similar filepath that matches the date (but one with YY and second YYYY):
c:\files\01MMYY\workbook1_01MMYYY.xlsx.

I was thinking about a do loop for a proc import statement to pull all of the workbooks into sas, but that seems like a lot to just try to get the number of observations in each workbook. However, I haven't found anything online that looks promising. Plus my loops aren't working for pulling in the workbooks:

```
    %let path=C:\files;
    %let dt=SEPT21;
    %let date=SEPT2021;
    %macro loop;
    %do i=1 %to 3;
        proc import datafile="&path\&i&&dt\woorkbook1_&i&&date..xlsx"
            dbms=xlxs replace
            out=hcw_&dt;
            range="'VCMR Data$'";
            getnames=yes;
        run;
    %end;
    %mend loop;`
```

Comment: Do you have SAS/ACCESS to Excel or PC Files? If so, you can read them natively in SAS with the Excel libname engine and get the observation count that way. SAS PC Files Server is free if you need it and it acts as the conduit between SAS and Excel.

Comment: Do all of the workbooks have the same sheets.  Why are you using RANGE statement instead of SHEET statement?  Do you only want to read in part of the worksheet?

Comment: Do you really have folders named `C:\files\1SEPT21` with only one digit for the day of the month?  And files named `woorkbook1_1SEPT2021.xlsx` with the double o in work?

Comment: Is there some specific column that you know will have a non-empty cell on the last row of the worksheet?  If so you could ask SAS to just import that column.  But if that column has empty cells at the end the count will be smaller than the result you would get if you imported the whole worksheet.

Comment: @Tom no, you're entirely correct - folder is 01SEPT21; workbook just has one "o" in work. This is what I get for trying to edit in a hurry! i did only want to read in a specific sheet but you're entirely correct - sheet would be more appropriate. I really like your idea of adding in the cell of the last row of the worksheet. that could be a good workaround. thanks for the ideas!

Comment: @StuSztukowski Thanks, Stu! I'll look into SAS PC Files Server.

Comment: As Joe said, it won't know the observations natively but it could make life a little easier. Say you knew all of your Excel files and sheets you wanted to read. You could count all the rows in a data step and save the count to a macro variable: `data _null_; set xl1.file1 xl2.file2 xl3.file3; call symputx('nobs', _N_); run;`

Comment: Also, another thing: if you have the right bitness of Excel installed already, you don't need PC Files Server. https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/acpcref/p0miuiasm9zgxin1hteqszu50rfe.htm. You can access it using the Excel access engine. https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/acpcref/p1py1764cw7zo5n1cr2bloubpr8m.htm

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a better way to do this in SAS, broadly speaking.  Unfortunately, SAS can't read the metadata of the excel file without importing it; a `libname` to the excel file would fail to provide you the counts.  You'll have to import the datasets.  (You could use `libname` to do the import, you just can't shortcut the import with a `proc contents` or checking `dictionary.tables` unfortunately).  There might be a better solution in another language, particularly .Net/Powershell if it can communicate with Excel without actually opening the file (but I'm not sure that's possible, either).

Your method should work, it's probably not the most efficient way, but fine; you don't sufficiently specify the particulars of the naming scheme, but assuming you can get that right, it will work well enough.  You do not though have the right naming scheme for `out` - the 1 to 3 loop overwrites the out datasets each time.

Probably what I'd do is import them all, and give the datasets names that are useful for your final dataset.  Say, `hcw_&dt._&i.`.  Then you can use `dictionary.tables` to get your final dataset.  Something like this (untested):

```
proc sql;
 create table want as
  select wb1.date, wb1.workbook1, wb2.workbook2, wb3.workbook3 
  from (
  select scan(memname,2,'_') as date, nobs as workbook1
    from dictionary.tables
    where libname='WORK' and memname like 'how%1'
       ) wb1
   left join
  (select scan(memname,2,'_') as date, nobs as workbook2
    from dictionary.tables
    where libname='WORK' and memname like 'how%2') wb2
   on wb1.date=wb2.date
   left join
  (select scan(memname,2,'_') as date, nobs as workbook3
    from dictionary.tables
    where libname='WORK' and memname like 'how%3') wb3
   on wb1.date=wb3.date
  ;
quit;
```